# Django model form for user profile won't pre-populate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've made a profile model in models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='title')
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='firstname')
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='lastname')
   blurb = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='tell us about yourself')

   #work out how to make filename equal the username
   pic = models.ImageField(default="static/profile/blank.png", upload_to='static/profile/%d%m%y.jpg')  #+ user.pk + '.jpg') 

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and here is the view for a page to edit the profile of a logged in user:

```
def editprofile(request):
   u_p = request.user.profile
   template = loader.get_template('registration/editprofile.html')

   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=u_p)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
      else:
          # todo
          None
   else:
      #todo

context = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The template fragment reads:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="regformout">
    <div class="regform">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class='cell'> {{ field.label_tag }} </div>
            <div class='nogin'> {{ field.errors }} </div>
            <div class='cell'> {{ field }} </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>

  <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save Your Profile" ></input>
</form>
```

I want the form fields to automatically populate with the data for the current user on the corresponding page for editing the profile. However, no matter what I try I cannot make this happen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your form is not being initialized if the `request.method` is not "POST". You should check your code! and that should normally throw an error since you are using `form` before it being initialized for a GET request.

Comment: The request method in the template is post. Also, putting the line: 'form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=u_p)' outside of any test for POST/GET still doesn't make it work. Your advice is good, but there is also something else going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you are only populating the form if the user hits the submit button, so when the view is requested initially, your form is empty.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def editprofile(request):
    u_p = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=u_p)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request,
                  'registration/editprofile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, this is still not happening! I really can't see why not as I'm sure I've made another form work in a nearly identical way. There must be something silly.

Comment: Perhaps the user it not logged in, as you are not checking for this.

Comment: I have another page to view the current profile which reads the profile of the current user and displays it. This is working so I think the user is logged in.

Comment: Ah, it was essentially as you said. There was a conflicting line also initializing the form in a place it should not have been. You method is now working. Thanks.